# batch processing : File name comparison error

Tags: bash, for-loop, batch-processing

I have written a program (Cifti_subject_fmri) which compares whether file name matches in two folders and essentially executes a set of instructions

```
 #!/bin/bash -- fix_mni_paths

    source activate ciftify_v1.0.0
    export SUBJECTS_DIR=/scratch/m/mchakrav/dev/functional_data
    export HCP_DATA=/scratch/m/mchakrav/dev/tCDS_ciftify
    ## make the $SUBJECTS_DIR if it does not already exist
    mkdir -p ${HCP_DATA}

    SUBJECTS=`cd $SUBJECTS_DIR; ls -1d *` ## list of my subjects
    HCP=`cd $HCP_DATA; ls -1d *` ## List of HCP Subjects 
    cd $HCP_DATA

    ## submit the files to the queue
    for i in $SUBJECTS;do

      for j in $HCP ; do

        if [[ $i == $j ]];then

           parallel "echo ciftify_subject_fmri $i/filtered_func_data.nii.gz $j fMRI " ::: $SUBJECTS |qbatch --walltime '05:00:00' --ppj 8 -c 4 -j 4 -N ciftify_subject_fmri -
        fi
    done
  done
```

When i run this code in the cluster i am getting an error which says

```
./Cifti_subject_fmri: [[AS1: command not found
```

The query ciftify_subject_fmri is part of toolbox ciftify, for it to execute it requires following instructions

```
ciftify_subject_fmri <func.nii.gz> <Subject> <NameOffMRI>
```

I have 33 subjects [AS1 -AS33] each with its own func.nii.gz files located SUBJECTS directory,the results need to be populated in HCP directory, fMRI is name of file format .

Could some one kindly let me know why i am getting an error in loop

Comment: So... The error is in `Cifti_subject_fmri`, but you've presumably included a different script in your question. (This one doesn't even have 36 lines.) Do you want to include the script that has the error?

Comment: @ghoti, actually its the same script , in the begining of the script i have to load several modules which has to do with freesurfer, FSL etc, i have not included that part of loading the modules, perhaps this cleared your confusion

Comment: Please check your code with shellcheck.net first.

Comment: This is to specific for us to help without the whole story.  Run your script with bash -x, at least you will be able to identify which line of code outputs the error.